# New Zealand working holiday visa medical requirements - UK citizen

Tags: visas, health, uk-citizens, new-zealand

I'm trying to find what medical examination and certification I need for the [New Zealand working holiday visa](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/visas/visa/united-kingdom-working-holiday-visa) as a UK citizen.

The only information I can find is [here](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/preparing-a-visa-application/medical-info/acceptable-standard-of-health-criteria-for-visa-approvals). This says that applicants "*may*" need to get a medical examination:

"You may need to get a medical examination as part of your application. We use this to determine if you meet the acceptable standard of health criteria."

It then links off to information about [chest x-rays here](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/preparing-a-visa-application/medical-info/when-you-need-an-x-ray-or-medical-examination), but this seems to only be relevant to applicants coming from countries without low TB rates. The website gives a list of countries with low TB rates and says if you are coming from one of these, you don't need the chest x-ray (UK is on the list.)

I can't find information around the things that need to be tested for. I have found some UK doctors offering immigration medical examinations for NZ, [such as here](https://www.knightsbridge-doctors.com/immigration-medical-new-zealand), but these seem to include x-rays?

Is there a list of things that need to be screened for as a UK citizen applying for this visa?

Comment: Will you get the 12 months or the 23 months visa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you linked [state](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/visas/visa/united-kingdom-working-holiday-visa)

> Tips
>
> - If you need to have an x-ray or medical examination after you apply online, we’ll send you an email explaining what to do.
> - If you apply for a 23 month visa, you must provide medical certificates, unless you > have sent them to us with another application and they were issued in the last 36 months.

The Medical requirements for a [WHV](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/preparing-a-visa-application/medical-info/whs-medical-reqs), state:

> **United Kingdom and Canada**
>
> If you are outside New Zealand and applying for a UK or Canada Working Holiday Visa for the maximum period of 23 months you must have a chest x-ray and general medical examination.

> If you apply for a 23-month visa, you must provide a General Medical Certificate.

This means that it's either compulsory (for a 23-month visa), or discretionary (for shorter visas)

---

A [General Medical Certificate (INZ 1007)](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/documents/forms-and-guides/inz1007.pdf) (along with other forms), which is usually to be sent electronically by a [INZ panel physician](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/preparing-a-visa-application/medical-info/panel-physicians) who you must seek if one is present in your country (if there **aren't any** panel physicians in your country the relevant forms can be mailed by another physician)

The Health Requirements for visa applicants are given in the form of [Health Requirements for entry to New Zealand (INZ 1121)](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/documents/forms-and-guides/inz1121.pdf) which you can check for yourself